# Trouble filtering an array of objects based on a nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I've got an array of objects that looks like this:

```
const nodes = [{
     post: 'a',
     categories: [{title:'Events'}, {title: 'Announcements'}]
     },
     {
     post: 'b',
     categories: [ {title:'Events'}]
     },
     {
     post: 'c',
     categories: [ {title:'Announcements'}]
     },
]
```

and I need to filter them based on arrays like this:

```
const sectionCategory1 = ['Events', 'Announcements']
const sectionCategory2 = ['Events']
```

so that only the posts that include the sectionCategory entries will remain.
For instance if I use sectionCategory2 the filter returns posts a and b.

I've tried the following:

```
const categoryNodes = nodes.filter((node => sectionCategory2.includes( node.categories.map(n => n.title))))
```

and

```
const categoryNodes = nodes.filter((node => sectionCategory2.includes( node.categories)))
```

didn't work either.
I'm sure there's something fundamental that I'm missing here and I know similar questions have been asked before but I've tried the other solutions and just keep beating my head against this.

Comment: Can you please provide the expected output you would like a working solution to produce?

Comment: If sectionCategory = sectionCategory1 result should be [{post:'a'}, {post:b}, {post:c}];
If sectionCategory = sectionCategory2 result should be  [{post:'a'}, {post:b}]
CertainPerformance had a good answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the iteration of a particular node, you have 2 arrays to check against each other: the categories to include, eg `['Events']`, and the category titles of the node, eg `['Events', 'Announcements']`. So, you'll need a nested loop, not just a single `.includes`: iterate over every element of one array to see if any matches an element in the other array.

```js
const nodes = [{
     post: 'a',
     categories: [{title:'Events'}, {title: 'Announcements'}]
     },
     {
     post: 'b',
     categories: [ {title:'Events'}]
     },
     {
     post: 'c',
     categories: [ {title:'Announcements'}]
     },
]
const sectionCategory2 = ['Events']
const categoryNodes = nodes.filter(
  node => node.categories.map(n => n.title)
    .some(title => 
      sectionCategory2.includes(title)
    )
);

console.log(categoryNodes);
```

Comment: This is a perfect explanation. Thanks!